# Pasar datos de funcion a otra funcion laravel

Tags: laravel, php7

Quiero pasar el dato $amigo_id que obtengo en nosematchh a verficarmartch pero al momento que hago me pide que le pase un dato

```
public function nosematchh(Request $data){
    $amigo_id = $data["elid"];
    return $amigo_id;
}
```

Pero el problema es que en nosematchh recibo los datos de la vista y no le puedo pasar otro dato como paso el resultado sin que me pida que le pase un dato.

```
 public function verificarmatch(){
        $amigo_id = $this->nosematchh();
        $resultado = Matchh::where("user_id",Auth::id())
            ->where("amigo_id",$amigo_id)
            ->first();
        if($resultado === null ){
            $existematch = 0;
        }else{
            $existematch = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez en lugar de llamar al método te convenga mas:

- Declarar una propiedad a nivel de la clase
- Que adquiera el valor dentro de `nosematchh()`
- Posterior poder invocar a esa propiedad con el valor adquirido ya en el método `verificarmatch`

Todo lo anterior así:

```
class TuControlador extends Controller
{
    public $amigoId = 0;

    public function nosematchh(Request $data)
    {
        $this->amigoId = $data["elid"];
    }

    public function verificarmatch()
    {
        $resultado = Matchh::where("user_id",Auth::id())
            ->where("amigo_id",$this->amigoId)
            ->first();

        if ($resultado === null ) {
            $existematch = 0;
        } else {
            $existematch = 1;
        }


}
```